# Exporting full prodcut catalog from Akeneo to Woocommerce using Webkul Woocmmerce Akeneo connector

Tags: woocommerce, export, akeneo

I've been playing around with the Webkul Woocommerce Akeneo connector module for a while and I'm suffering with major reliability issues with it.

I've got a catalog of ~1500products, ~200 categories, 30 attributes & ~900 attribute options. The catalog also includes simple and variable products with one or two variant axes.

These are the problems I face constantly with the connector:

- On full export (categories, attributes, attribute options & products) the process usually fails somewhere around 600-900 imported products
- Products won't find their categories in Woocommerce. Especially sub-categories seems to be very tricky.
- If I export products in batches, the export process works better on first batch but then categories and attributes tend to "mix up" on following batches.

During the export, there's no critcal warnings or fail messages showing up.

Any help appreciated.

Akeneo version 5.0 CE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about Akeneo PHP memory overflow and Akeneo export batch size.

Around 800-900 imported products, the memory exceeds the 512M limit. 1024M limit to php.ini did the trick.

Lowering the job batch size from 100/batch to 50/batch also increased the export process speed.